# Удалить метки без вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, удаление-метки, мета

Как насчёт того, чтобы избавиться от **всех** меток на Мете, у которых `0` вопросов, зараз?

**Дополнение**

Подобные метки можно найти на странице [Меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) и, как указали в ответе, это по большей части замена для основных меток. Однако из-за того, что метки-замены никак не отличаются от остальных, то выглядит как будто по ним и впрямь нет никаких (0) вопросов.

Comment: Приведите их список хотя бы. А то как-то беспредметно ..

Answer (score 5):

Хорошо бы, конечно, привести примеры таких меток.

Но, в любом случае, метки с `0` вопросов по ним автоматические удаляются скриптом.

На мете в [общем списке вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?page=10&tab=popular) на первый взгляд много меток, по которым нет вопросов, но это не так, это, по большей части, синонимы.