# Не почистить ли мету от неиспользуемых меток?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, удаление-метки, мета

На мете довольно много пустых меток. То есть меток, с которыми нет вопросов. Но в списке меток найти эти "пустышки" можно, просто они находятся на последних страницах.

На мете есть три страницы пустых меток! Какие-то из них с русскими названиями,какие-то с английскими. Страницы 7 - 10 списка всех меток состоят только из таких "пустышек".
Иногда попадаются метки-дубликаты, они тоже лишние, как и вопросы-дубликаты.

Не пора ли "почистить" мету от неиспользуемых меток? Вроде бы эти метки ни кому не мешают, но всё-таким как-то неправильно,что есть куча такого "мусора". И я предлагаю сделать на `мете` генеральную уборку, чтобы весь мусор сразу выкинуть.

**Дополнение:**

Я глянул, эти метки вроде как не обязательны, поэтому удалить их технически возможно. Многие из этих меток связаны с другими, но вопросов с ними нет.

Comment: Есть предположение, что эти пустышки так просто не удалить, потому что они своего рода "стандартные" метки, которые автоматически присутствуют на любой мете. Иначе как объяснить, что они сплошь на английском.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight
 не все на английском, хотя и многие.

Comment: Те, которые на русском, являются необъединенными синонимами других меток (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/зимошляп)

Comment: До этого закрыл как дубликат не того вопроса. Вот дубликат: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10199/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2

Comment: [7 лет почти миновало](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287563/339911), а воз и [ныне тут](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bptG6.png).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Наличие некоторых неиспользуемых меток обусловлено существованием синонимов (которые, правда, тоже не используются). Например, [bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks). Некоторые другие метки из конца списка, которые живы, но не имеют вопросов, вероятно носят какой-то служебный характер (как уже предположили в комментарии). Так как обычно неиспользованные метки должны удаляться автоматически через некоторое время. [Можно попробовать это выяснить на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385889/339911).

В целом, я не вижу серьёзной проблемы в существовании таких меток в списке. Они никак не мешают навигации по сайту или постановке и поиску вопросов. Но может быть кто-то сможет мне возразить и показать ситуацию, когда без них было бы действительно удобнее и проще пользоваться сайтом. Было бы интересно узнать.

Пока что для меня предложение удалить эти метки проявило лишь интерес к тому, почему они не удалились автоматически. А их удаление нужно только для удовлетворения перфекционизма (в идеале их, конечно же, быть не должно).

Comment: Интересно, метки вроде как должны удаляться, если с ними нет вопросов долгое время.  Но этого, видимо, не происходит, иначе бы этих меток вообще бы не было.  Может, их система создаёт? В большинстве своём эти метки необязательны. С синонимами правда: часто пустышки являются синонимами других меток, но от них пользы всё равно нет .

Comment: @Зонтик по ссылке на MSE дали ответ о причинах существования этих меток. Синонимы удобны для упрощения ввода и т.к. люди иногда ошибаются.

Comment: @Зонтик у синонимов нет отдельного описания. Это не предусмотрено.